# Stability of a negative feedback amplifier

Tags: amplifier, feedback

Consider a negative feedback amplifier whose open loop gain is A(jw) and whose feedback factor is F(jw).

- We all know that the Oscillation Criterion is A(jw)F(jw)=-1

To evaluate the stability, the frequency Phase-Crossover Angular Frequency **fp** is defined as the frequency at which the angle of A(jw)F(jw) is -pi

and the frequency Gain-Crossover Angular Frequency **fg** is defined as the frequency at which the amplitute of A(jw)F(jw) is 1

I read in the text book that if fp < fg, for the frequency between fp and fg, the amplifier is not stable.

- my question is for frequency between fp and fg A(jw)F(jw) is not -1, how could the amplifier be not stable?
  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"*I read in the text book that if fp < fg, for the frequency between fp and fg, the amplifier is not stable.*"

Please, can you quote the relevant part of the textbook? This sentence sounds as if the author thinks, that the amplifier could be unstable for some certain input frequencies only ("between fp and fg").

Here is my answer: If a system with feedback does not fulfill the stability criterion (negative phase margin and/or gain margin), it will be unstable and either oscillate or go into saturation. This effect is **independent** on the frequency of the input signal. Rather, it is an effect of self-excitement.